# Symfony translation messages with arrays, find length

Tags: arrays, symfony, twig, yaml, translation

**Setup:**

Consider the situation of a multilingual site built with Symfony 3, using YAML files for translation messages and TWIG templates for display.

In one section of content, in English, there should be an instruction showing 3 items each representing a step of a process. In German there should only be 2, while in Spanish there are 50.

The setup for this may be for example:

```
#messages.en.yaml
root_node:
    -
        title: English title 1
        item: Some first list item
    -
        title: English title 2
        item: Some second list item
    -
        title: English title 3
        item: Some third list item


#messages.de.yaml
root_node:
    -
        title: German title 1
        item: Some other first list item
    -
        title: German title 2
        item: Some second German list item


#messages.es.yaml
root_node:
    -
        title: Spanish title 1
        item: Some Spanish first list item
    ...

etc ...
```

Considering this structure, ideally, I would like the template to read the fact that `root_node` is an array, get it's length so that we can display the total number of steps, then create a structure in the twig template that loops over the array and outputs the steps as some translated title and item text.

Attempting to read the array length by `{{'root_node'|length}}` and `{{('root_node'|trans)|length}}` just give the length of the text though and `{{root_node|length}}` gives an error as the variable is not in the scope of the template, because it should be looked up through the translation service.

**Question:**

How can I read the length of the array at this translation key?
Should this even be attempted in this manner? If not, is there a best practice for translating arrays of unknown size (dependent on translation language) in Symfony?

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct ability to achieve such behavior into Symfony translator. However it can be achieved indirectly by using [pluralization](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#pluralization) mechanism in Symfony.

You can set custom pluralization logic by using [`PluralizationRules::set`](https://web.archive.org/web/20170627123704/http://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/Translation/PluralizationRules.html#method_set) method and then call [`Translator::transChoice`](https://web.archive.org/web/20170704075810/http://api.symfony.com:80/3.3/Symfony/Component/Translation/Translator.html#method_transChoice) with passing step number as argument for choice. You will need to use [`transchoice(index)`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#translation-tags) filter into your template to obtain required step.

You can obtain list of steps for particular locale by counting them separately from [translation catalogue](https://web.archive.org/web/20170704075810/http://api.symfony.com:80/3.3/Symfony/Component/Translation/Translator.html#method_getCatalogue) and passing to template. Alternatively, depending on your application's logic, you can simply obtain translated message for current step and test if it is empty string or not.

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting solution so +1 for ingenuity, although I have to admit it does seem a little odd to be overloading the meaning of the pluralisation like this. Well... apparently I can't even +1 you, because SO. :/